# Get original filename when downloading with WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

Is there any way to know the original name of a file you download using the WebClient when the Uri doesn't contain the name?

This happens for example in sites where the download originates from a dynamic page where the name isn't known beforehand.

Using my browser, the file gets the orrect name. But how can this be done using the WebClient?
E.g.

```
        WebClient wc= new WebClient();
        var data=   wc.DownloadData(@"www.sometime.com\getfile?id=123");
```

Using DownloadFile() isn't a solution since this method needs a filename in advance.

Comment: Have you tried checking `wc.ResponseHeaders`? File downloads usually contain an attachment header with the filename.

Comment: Tobberoth. That indeed is the answer! Didn't know that. Thank you very very much!

Comment: Some sites with downloads from dynamic pages generates redirects and don't set the "Content-Disposition" on the redirected response, so you can use HttpClient with AutoRedirect=false, use the HEAD method and then get the "location" header from the response.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to examine the response headers and see if there is a content-disposition header present which includes the actual filename.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
var data=   wc.DownloadData(@"www.sometime.com\getfile?id=123");
string fileName = "";

// Try to extract the filename from the Content-Disposition header
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(wc.ResponseHeaders["Content-Disposition"]))
{
 fileName = wc.ResponseHeaders["Content-Disposition"].Substring(wc.ResponseHeaders["Content-Disposition"].IndexOf("filename=") + 9).Replace("\"", "");
}
```

Comment: The `System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition` can be used to parse the header `var header = new ContentDisposition(wc.ResponseHeaders["Content-Disposition"]);`

Answer (score 6):

Read the Response Header `"Content-Disposition"` with [WebClient.ResponseHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.responseheaders%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It should be:

```
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
```

your code should look like:

```
string header = wc.ResponseHeaders["Content-Disposition"]??string.Empty;
const string filename="filename=";
int index = header.LastIndexOf(filename,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
if (index > -1)
{
    fileName = header.Substring(index+filename.Length);
}
```

Comment: Good answer but the index needs to be advanced to account for the length of "filename=".  IMHO I'd change it to fileName = header.Substring(index + "filename=".Length);

Answer (score 3):

To get the filename without downloading the file:

```
public string GetFilenameFromWebServer(string url)
{
    string result = "";

    var req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
    req.Method = "HEAD";
    using (System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
    {
        // Try to extract the filename from the Content-Disposition header
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resp.Headers["Content-Disposition"]))
        {
            result = resp.Headers["Content-Disposition"].Substring(resp.Headers["Content-Disposition"].IndexOf("filename=") + 9).Replace("\"", "");
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you, like me, have to deal with a Content-Disposition header that is not formatted correctly or cannot be parsed automatically by the ContentDisposition class for some reason, here's my solution :

```
string fileName = null;

// Getting file name
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "HEAD";

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    // Headers are not correct... So we need to parse manually
    var contentDisposition = response.Headers["Content-Disposition"];

    // We delete everything up to and including 'Filename="'
    var fileNameMarker= "filename=\"";
    var beginIndex = contentDisposition.ToLower().IndexOf(fileNameMarker);
    contentDisposition = contentDisposition.Substring(beginIndex + fileNameMarker.Length);

    //We only get the string until the next double quote
    var fileNameLength = contentDisposition.ToLower().IndexOf("\"");
    fileName = contentDisposition.Substring(0, fileNameLength);
}
```