# Downloading Files from website without knowing file name then extracting and moving to set location

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm trying to download files using a list of urls. how would i go about downloading the files if your urls only end in the page where you would normally click the download button(it has a redirect and wait on the download also)?

i havent actually managed to get further than downloading a file using
but i know this wont work because i wont be able to know the filename and ill have to save it to a file in a config location

```
  using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
 {
  client.DownloadFile("https://github.com/Hellzbellz123/downloadme/raw/master/TestAddon.7z", "testAddon.7z");
 }
```

I intend to build a backend then plug it into a windows forms app for a gui because im really new to C# and programming in general

Comment: You can use FTP instead of WebClient which has a method to get filenames in folder.  See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/079fb811-3c55-4959-85c4-677e4b20bea3/downloading-all-files-in-directory-ftp-and-c?forum=ncl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you don't know the filenames so you don't know how to save them locally?
If so:

```
//with 'url' as string
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Uri uri = new Uri(url);

client.DownloadFile(uri, uri.Segments.Last());
```

It takes the URL and splits it by every slash - the last item in the list is the filename..

EDIT: Improved, thanks to [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/)

That method won't work for links like "[..]/download.php?fileid="

For those links take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492355/get-original-filename-when-downloading-with-webclient)

Comment: `Uri uri = new Uri(@"https://github.com/Hellzbellz123/downloadme/raw/master/TestAddon.7z") => Console.WriteLine(uri.Segments.Last());`

Comment: the website in question is curseforge
when you click download the url goes from
https://www.curseforge.com/wow/addons/btw-quests --> https://www.curseforge.com/wow/addons/btw-quests/download -->https://www.curseforge.com/wow/addons/btw-quests/download/2699298/file

Comment: that number also seems to change with what file you download AND with different downloads

Comment: Take a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492355/get-original-filename-when-downloading-with-webclient)